# C# Entity Framework Invalid object name 'sys.default_constraints'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

No meu projeto em C# MVC 5 com Entity Framework junto a um Servidor SQL Server, dentre uma série de classes, tenho uma classe chamada ctmdMandados.cs:

```
public class ctmdMandados
{
    //cadastro dos mandados recebidos e seus status
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //outras propriedades

    public virtual int TipoDocID { get; set; }
    public virtual ctmdTipoDoc TipoDoc { get; set; }


}
```

Ocorre que antes a variável TipoDoc era um Enum local com valores fixos, devidamente migrado no Entity Framework. Porém, durante a modelagem, decidi criar uma nova classe para o TipoDoc, com uma nova tabela, chave primária e tudo mais. Antes dessa alteração, o banco de dados estava funcionando normalmente, sem nenhuma migração pendente.

```
public class ctmdTipoDoc
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(12)]
    public string TipoDoc { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<ctmdMandados> Mandados { get; set; }

}
```

E depois mapeei em DbContext:

```
public class AplicacoesContexto: DbContext
{
//outros mapeamentos
    public DbSet<ctmdTipoDoc> ctmdTipo { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
//outros modelbuilders
        var ctmdTipoBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity<ctmdTipoDoc>();
        ctmdTipoBuilder.ToTable("ctmdTipo");

        modelBuilder.Entity<ctmdTipoDoc>()
            .HasMany(ctmdTipo => ctmdTipo.Mandados)
            .WithRequired(ctmdMandados => ctmdMandados.TipoDoc);
}
```

Após, executei o código para adicionar uma nova migracao, e o Entity Framework: criou o seguinte(colei só o Up):

```
public partial class Atualiza : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.ctmdTipo",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    TipoDoc = c.String(maxLength: 12),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        AddColumn("dbo.ctmdMandados", "TipoDocID", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        CreateIndex("dbo.ctmdMandados", "TipoDocID");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.ctmdMandados", "TipoDocID", "dbo.ctmdTipo", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
        DropColumn("dbo.ctmdMandados", "Tipo");
    }}
```

Ao tentar executar o update-database, o Package Manager Console gera o erro *Invalid object name 'sys.default.constraints'* (ultima linha):

```
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Applying explicit migrations: [201602252013494_Atualiza].
Applying explicit migration: 201602252013494_Atualiza.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'sys.default_constraints'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinNewTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClass30.<ExecuteStatements>b__2e()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
ClientConnectionId:b0d48a01-5a3f-469d-bd07-70a280743ba9
Invalid object name 'sys.default_constraints'.
```

Pesquisei na internet mas não encontrei nada definitivo. Penso que tenha a ver com os padrões junto ao SQL Server, mas não tenho ideia de como resolver.

Obrigado mais uma vez pela atenção!

Comment: Qual a versão do SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server 2010 ou 2012, creio eu. O servidor não fica no meu departamento.

Comment: O usuário do banco possui alguma limitação de acesso?

Comment: Não ao database selecionado. Não consigo entrar nos database de outros departamentos no mesmo servidor

Comment: Você consegue executar com o seu usuário o seguinte? `select * from sys.default_constraints`

Comment: Prezado, confesso que já sai do trabalho no momento, farei o teste amanhã :)

Comment: tente retira seu dbo.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Ao tentar efetuar a consulta no SQL server retorna o mesmo erro "Invalid object name 'SYS.DEFAULT_CONSTRAINTS'."...que estranho

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza desculpe, nao entendi o que devo fazer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não há nada de errado com o Entity Framework. Apenas seu login não possui permissões.

Verifique com a equipe responsável pelo banco de dados se há algum `DENY` para os metadatabases ou ainda se o login não tem a role `public` configurada.

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda! A demora na minha marcação como resposta se deu por conta da equipe que coordena o banco de dados ter demorado pra adequá-lo =)